# Android app package name on internal test release

Tags: android, flutter, testing, google-play-console, internals

I created an android app using flutter After it was released for internal testing the app download page on google play shows the app name as the flutter package name. I changed the app name from the app settings on google play console, but it is still the same.

Is it because of the internal testing app? will it be okay after moved to production?

Answer (score 1):

please be sure you changed you app name in AndroidManifest.xml

go to android => app => src => main => AndroidManifest.xml and change `android:label="you app name"` and `android:name="${applicationName}"`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to the tooltip on the google play console, seems the app name take temporarily name in testing stage